# AJAX call sometimes stores the wrong value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have online examination portal, in which a user selects an answer and clicks next. At this point I make an AJAX call.

With each AJAX call I insert one row into the database. I'm storing `marks` as floats.

It should store either `1` or `-0.25`, but sometimes it stores `0`, and I can't find the problem.

Here is my code:

**Jquery Code:**

```
var questin = $("#ques"+next).val(); var secin = $("#sect"+next).val();
$.ajax({ 
     data:{ques:questin,answ:n,sec:secin}, 
     method:'post', 
     async:false, 
     url:'result.php',
     success:function(data){ 

     } 
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
    include("action/db.php");
    session_start();
    $ques_id = $_REQUEST['ques'];
    $mark = (float) $_REQUEST['answ'];
    $sec = $_REQUEST['sec'];
    $exam_date_id = $_SESSION['ex_da'];
    $use_id =  $_SESSION['uid'];
    $run->db_open();
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useranswers WHERE question_id='$ques_id' AND user_id='$use_id'");
    $no = mysql_num_rows($query2);

    if($no==0){
        $date = date("Y:m:d:h:m:s");
        $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO useranswers VALUES ('','$exam_date_id','$use_id','$ques_id',0,'$sec','$mark','0','0','$date')");
    }else{
        $query1 = mysql_query("UPDATE useranswers SET mark='$mark' WHERE question_id='$ques_id'");  
    }
    $run->db_close();
?>
```

Comment: Please write your ajax fucntiom also.

Comment: can **-0.25** stored as float datatype?

Comment: var n = $("input:checked","#check"+next).val();                                   var questin = $("#ques"+next).val();
 var secin = $("#sect"+next).val();
 
 $.ajax({
  
  data:{ques:questin,answ:n,sec:secin},
  method:'post',
  async:false,
  url:'result.php',
  success:function(data){
  }
  
  
 });

Comment: ya we can store Its taking the values for 10 or 15 questions but sometimes it stores the value zero.

Comment: what is the value of  `n` at your client side before making ajax call ? is it in passing `float` value ?

Comment: n is selected radio button value. n value having marks. ya yes n having the float value